# unable to save Curl session cookie

Tags: php, cookies, curl, session-cookies

I'm trying to scrap with login and password,

I use this script to pass the login page :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.cogedim-partenaire.com/extranet/cogedim_extranet_prod/verification_id.php"); //login URL
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$postData="login=XXX&mdp=XXX";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$store = curl_exec ($ch);
return $ch;

?>
```

In fact, my problem is that I do not manage to get cookie.txt on my server....

I checked the Chmod, and no problem with this,

However, I do not get the cookie after passing the login page...

Does somebody can help me ?

Many thanks,

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path for the cookie file instead of relative path. For example:

```
/tmp/curl/cookie.txt
```

Also, close your curl after the operation is finish.

```
curl_close($ch);
```